# Getting JSON Data using Http in Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework, module, angular2-http

Having troubles with Ionic getting data from a JSON File via HTTP, I dont know what is the problem the error is quite strange.

[image: error message in chrome devtool]

here are the codes :

`src/pages/subhome/line/line.ts` (The Subhome contains a few folders of pages)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
/**
 * Generated class for the LinePage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-line',
  templateUrl: 'line.html',
})
export class LinePage {

  commands: any[] = []

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('line.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe((data) => {
      this.commands = data.json();
      console.log(this.commands);
    })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LinePage');
  }

}
```

and here is the JSON file :

`src/pages/subhome/line/line.json`

```js
{
 "commands": [{
   "title": "a",
   "desc": "b"
  },
  {
   "title": "a",
   "desc": "b"
  },
  {
   "title": "a",
   "desc": "b"
  },
  {
   "title": "a",
   "desc": "b"
  }
 ]
}
```

**What I'm trying to do is "logging" the JSON commands to the console**
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

move your JSON file to assets folder, 
and call it via

```
this.http.get('assets/line.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP methods are used to make calls to remote servers.
As far as i know these methods are not used to call any file within your app
For passing data among pages you can use something like this `this.navController.push(SecondPage, {
    param1: 'firstname', param2: 'lastname'
});`

see tutorial [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/passing-data-between-pages-in-ionic-2/)

If it is JSON data that you want to access, consider storing it in a variable or you can use the local storage like below

```
this.storage.set('myData', data);
```

Dont forget to import and inject

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
constructor (public storage: Storage){}
```